# Efficient way of communicating variables between a Dialog Fragment and an Activity?

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

My main activity sets up and begins a dialog fragment for the user to interact with.  The dialog displays several radio buttons to choose and can cancel or accept the choice when done.  The main activity employs an interface to check the event once the dialog fragment has been dismissed and then changes a local variable according to the same variable that exists in the dialog fragment.  This seems really redundant to me so is there a better way to achieve this communication?  Take a look at the NOTI_TIMER in main activity.

Main activity:

```
    public void dialogSetup(){

    RadioButtonDialog dialog = new RadioButtonDialog();

    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Radio Button Dialog");
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

    NOTI_TIMER = RadioButtonDialog.getNOTI();
    startAlarm();
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

    log("in onDialogNegativeClick");
}
```

Dialog Fragment:

```
public class RadioButtonDialog extends DialogFragment{

public String TAG = "RadioButtonDialog";
public static long NOTI_TIMER = 0;

RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
Button timerChoice;

/* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
 * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
 * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
public interface RadioButtonDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
RadioButtonDialogListener mListener;

// Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (RadioButtonDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle SavedInstanceState){

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_choice_layout, null);
mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setTitle("Choose Selfie Timer Duration");
//timerChoice = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.delete_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "User pressed 'Cancel'.");
        mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(RadioButtonDialog.this);

    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.timer_btn_confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        switch (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){

        case R.id.radioButton1:
            NOTI_TIMER = 10800000;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.three_hours, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton2:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.six_hours, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            NOTI_TIMER = 21600000;
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton3:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.nine_hours, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            NOTI_TIMER = 32400000;
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton4:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.twelve_hours, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            NOTI_TIMER = 43200000;
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton5:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.twentyfour_hours, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            NOTI_TIMER = 86400000;
            break;

        }
        mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(RadioButtonDialog.this);
    }
});

Dialog dialog = builder.create();
return(dialog);
}

public static long getNOTI() {

    return NOTI_TIMER;
}
```

}

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from passing NOTI_TIMER as a parameter directly in the onDialogNegativeClick() callback. Have a look at the java Observable class(along with the Observer interface).

Comment: NegativeClick should remain empty because I am not changing anything if the user cancels the dialog.  Unless I misunderstood your comment.  I should mention that the code works just fine, I just need to know if there is a more elegant way to pass a variable than just setting it to whatever the fragment's local variable is.